# Passing ref up to parent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little app that has an input and based on the search value, displays weather for a particular city. I'm stuck at a certain point though. The idea is that once you search a city, it hides the text input and search button and displays some weather info and another search button to search a new city. My issue is that I want to focus on the search box once I click to search again. I hope that makes sense. I read that the ideal way to do this is with `refs`. I wired it up like such:

```
class WeatherForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.city = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.passRefUpward(this.city);
    this.city.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.isOpen) {
      return (
        <div className={style.weatherForm}>
          <form action='/' method='GET'>
            <input 
              ref={this.city} 
              onChange={this.props.updateInputValue} 
              type='text' 
              placeholder='Search city' 
            />
            <input 
              onClick={e => this.props.getWeather(e)} 
              type='submit' 
              value='Search' 
            /> 
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className={style.resetButton}>
          <p>Seach another city?</p>
          <button 
            onClick={this.props.resetSearch}>Search
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

With this I can pass that ref up to the parent to use in my search by using `this.state.myRefs.current.value;` It works great, but when I try to reference `this.state.myRefs.current` in a different function to use `.focus()`, it returns `null`.

```
resetSearch = () => {
    console.log(this.state.myRefs.current); // <- returns null

    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
      details: [],
      video: []
    });
  }
```

Is this because I'm hiding and showing different components based on the search click? I've read numerous posts on SO, but I still can't crack this. Any help is appreciated. I'll include the full code below. To see it in full here is the git repo: https://github.com/DanDeller/tinyWeather/blob/master/src/components/WeatherMain.js

```
class Weather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      recentCities: [],
      details: [],
      isOpen: true,
      myRefs: '',
      video: '',
      city: ''
    };

    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    this.getRefsFromChild = this.getRefsFromChild.bind(this);
    this.resetSearch = this.resetSearch.bind(this);
    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
  }

  updateInputValue = (e) => {
    ...
  }

  resetSearch = () => {
    console.log(this.state.myRefs.current);

    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
      details: [],
      video: []
    });
  }

  getWeather = (e) => {
    ...
  }

  getRefsFromChild = (childRefs) => {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className={style.container}>
        <div className={style.weatherMain + ' ' + style.bodyText}>
          <video key={this.state.video} className={style.video} loop autoPlay muted>
            <source src={this.state.video} type="video/mp4">
            </source>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
          <div className={style.hold}>
            <div className={style.weatherLeft}>
              <WeatherForm
                updateInputValue={this.updateInputValue}
                getWeather={this.getWeather}
                passRefUpward={this.getRefsFromChild}
                resetSearch={this.resetSearch}
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}

              />
              <WeatherList
                details={this.state.details}
                city={this.state.city}
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={style.weatherRight}>
              <Sidebar
                recentCities={this.state.recentCities}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={style.clear}></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}


class WeatherForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.city = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.passRefUpward(this.city);
    this.city.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.isOpen) {
      return (
        <div className={style.weatherForm}>
          <form action='/' method='GET'>
            <input 
              ref={this.city} 
              onChange={this.props.updateInputValue} 
              type='text' 
              placeholder='Search city' 
            />
            <input 
              onClick={e => this.props.getWeather(e)} 
              type='submit' 
              value='Search' 
            /> 
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className={style.resetButton}>
          <p>Seach another city?</p>
          <button 
            onClick={this.props.resetSearch}>Search
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Weather;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to achieve unmounted component from DOM, because of this you can not catch the reference. If you put this code your instead of render function of WeatherForm component, you can catch the reference. Because i just hide it, not remove from DOM.

```
  render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={style.weatherForm}
                     style={this.props.isOpen ? {visibility:"initial"} :{visibility:"hidden"}}>
                    <form action='/' method='GET'>
                        <input
                            ref={this.city}
                            onChange={this.props.updateInputValue}
                            type='text'
                            placeholder='Search city'
                        />
                        <input
                            onClick={e => this.props.getWeather(e)}
                            type='submit'
                            value='Search'
                        />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className={style.resetButton} style={this.props.isOpen ? {visibility:"hidden"} :{visibility:"initial"}}>
                    <p>Seach another city?</p>
                    <button
                        onClick={this.props.resetSearch}>Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
   }
```

Comment: Good call with hiding versus removing. I figured that was the issue. Can't believe I didn't think of this solution in the first place. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

console.log(this.state.myRefs.current) returns null , because it's a reference to an input dom element which does not exists as currently Weather form is displaying Search another city along with a reset button.

In reset function state changes, which  results  in change  of prop isOpen for WeatherForm component. Now, screen would be displaying the input field along with search button.

After component is updated ComponentDidUpdate lifecycle method is called.

Please add ComponentDidUpdate lifecycle method in WeatherForm and add ,
this.city.current.focus()  in the body of method.

There is no need to pass reference of a dom  element to the parent element as it is not consider as a good practise.

Edit 1 :-

Need to set input field in focus only if prop ( isOpen ) is true as we will get reference to the input field only if its mounted.

```
ComponentDidUpdate(){
if(this props.isOpen)
this.city.current.focus
}
```

Link to Lifecycle method :- 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sahil. I tired that one too but that gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null`.

Comment: Can you please console.log(this.city.current) in component did mount. Does the input field is focused the very first time you search for a weather in particular city ?

Comment: So if I use `console.log(this.city.current)` inside the componentDidMount(), I see the `<input type="text" placeholder="Search city">`. Crazy how some thing that seems so small is kicking me around! And yes when I load the page, `componentDidMount()` works to focus that input.

Comment: I have updated the answer  .. one condition was missing